# WordPress: can't access Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, https, wordpress-theming, connection-timeout

I was editing my site yesterday and everything was fine. I was doing a bit of cleanup and deleted the default 2013, 2014, and 2015 themes, keeping only my parent and child themes. I didn't know that it is recommended to keep one of those to fall back on. A few hours later I tried to log in again and the request timed out. I've tried multiple times on multiple browsers, no luck.

After some research I changed the name of my plugin folder, and all my individual plugins, and I re-installed and activated the Twenty Fifteen theme using cPanel. I changed the name of my parent & child theme folders. I also increased the WP memory limit in wp-config.php. I cleared my browser cache & cookies. I still can't get in to the dashboard.

My site is [here](http://wheeliecart.com.au). It now loads with the Twenty Fifteen theme, but I still can't get the wp-admin page to load.

Thanks for any help.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the https:// (as opposed to http://) at the beginning of the url, because going to /wp-admin redirects to https://your-site.com/wp-admin , I have had issues with that on other WP sites.

Comment: It seems to be an issue when it hits https @ https://wheeliecart.com.au/ which is what wp_admin redirects to. http seems to be fine.

Comment: go and download the 2015 theme and put it in the wp-include/themes/ and put it in there

Comment: @JackSmith I don't have a wp-include/themes/ folder. But I did already download the 2015 theme and put it in wp-content/themes/ ... my site is currently running on 2015, but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: yes i ment wp-content folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest methods, I suggest you delete the wp-admin folder and wp-include folder that is present, you can remove the via the main FTP. after that, you upload files wp-admin & wp-include folder. You may be using the latest version of the Wordpress or another version you want. And try again.

Comment: I copied those two folders into a new folder, deleted the originals, and then re-added the copies, but it didn't do anything. I deleted the originals and added new versions of the two folders from a fresh download of WordPress, still nothing.

Comment: currently wp-admin it redirect to https: you have to change site url at database in the wp_options tables look to the  column siteurl change it to http: